# Word or phrase: To convince others to do wrong

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes somebody who convinces other people to do wrong.

"Coercion" comes close, but I'm looking for something that doesn't imply a threat.

"Ducking" is a prison-slang term for when a prisoner gets the guards to do things for them.  I would be happy with this except that it's very specific.

"Brainwashing" is almost halfway close, but not really.

Real-life examples are rather grim, such as a person who convinces another to be a suicide-bomber, or perhaps racism in general.

> I'm a racist because I was _____ed
>
> Watch out for Henry, he's a ______

I would be particularly happy with an answer if the word/phrase was meant to be used as an insult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone who is encouraging others to do something wrong is ***abetting*** them (and so they are an ***abettor***). It does not necessarily involve force (and hence there is no *coercion* in general) and yes, they are sometimes considered to be guilty along with those who committed the wrong deed.

> Watch out for Henry, he's an ***abettor***.

ODO:

> **[abet](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abet)**
>   *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Encourage or assist (someone) to do something wrong, in particular to commit a crime.
>
> ‘he was not guilty of murder but was guilty of aiding and abetting
>   others’
>
> **[abettor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abettor)** (also **abetter**)
>   *NOUN*
>   A person who encourages or assists someone to do something wrong, in particular to commit a crime.
>
> ‘she pleaded guilty to manslaughter as an aider and abettor’

Answer (score 1):

You may use the term ***[corrupt:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/corrupt)***

> if someone is corrupted by something, it causes them to become dishonest and unjust and unable to be trusted.

Corrupt (adj):

> Someone who is corrupt behaves in a way that is morally wrong, especially by doing dishonest or illegal things in return for money or power.

(Collins)

Answer (score 1):

As a verb, **manipulate**:

> to control or play upon by artful, unfair, or insidious means especially to one's own advantage
>   <sub>[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/manipulate)</sub>

You could use the noun **manipulator**, but if you're looking for something insulting I'd suggest **manipulative snake**. "Snake" is a generic, insulting term meaning ["a worthless or treacherous fellow"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snake), but in this case it could also be used as a biblical reference for the snake in Eden who convinced Eve to eat the apple.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of words that might fit. There are various connotations depending on what you have in mind.

```
encouraged
inflamed
inspired
instigated
motivated
provoked
roused
set off
spurred
triggered
urged
whipped up
activated
coaxed
driven
excited
goaded
induced
influenced
persuaded
raised
solicited
stimulated
keyed up
psyched
put up to
stirred up
talked into
work up
```

Comment: Do they all mean the same thing? Are they all interchangeable? Would they all fit the sentences provided by the OP with the suggested sense? What are the differences in usage of each term? Just providing a list is of no real help.

Answer (score 0):

- I'm a racist because I was manipulated.
- I'm a racist because I was uneducated.
- I'm a racist because I was uniformed.
- Watch out for Henry, he's a twist.
- Watch out for Henry, he's a bad influence.
- Watch out for Henry, he's a manipulator.